# How to save rendered DOM block after dragging?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use Angular CDK and drag directive attached to div block.

Each block is rendered in loop:

```
<div *ngFor="let block of blocks" cdkDrag></div>
```

So, as result I get some draggable blocks on the page.

When I remove or add element to array of blocks all rendered before blocks are rerendered.

How to save position each of block if they were dragged?

I have tried trackBy, it not working

Comment: How do you add new/remove elements from array? Share that code also your `drop` handler

Comment: I use push, or splice functions , i dont have handler function just directive

Comment: you don't have a `(cdkDropListDropped)` ?